# How does key as function of a map and vice versa both work the same way in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

```
({:x 10, :y 20, :z 50} :y)
gives 20
```

and also

```
(:y {:x 10, :y 20, :z 50})
gives 20
```

How does it work internally in both cases,

For maps as function, I can understand that you can differentiate the form by understanding the first value is a map.

but how does key become a function ? at runtime, key could be any type of value, so how does the runtime understand that it has to treat this value as a function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maps are functions, from the [docs](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Maps%20%28IPersistentMap%29):

> Maps implement IFn, for invoke() of one argument (a key) with an optional second argument (a default value), i.e. maps are functions of their keys. nil keys and values are ok.

So this:

```
({:x 10, :y 20, :z 50} :y)
```

applies function `{:x 10, :y 20, :z 50}` to `:y`.

Keywords are functions too, quoting the [docs](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Keywords):

> Keywords implement IFn for invoke() of one argument (a map) with an optional second argument (a default value). For example (:mykey my-hash-map :none) means the same as (get my-hash-map :mykey :none)

So you when you do:

```
(:y {:x 10, :y 20, :z 50})
```

you actually invoke `:y` with `{:x 10, :y 20, :z 50}` as argument.

Basically anything that implements `IFn` and is on the classpath can be treated as a function.

Comment: So basically, anything other than keywords as key wont work in this case.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar unless it also implements `IFn` in the same way as keywords, no.

Comment: It may look non-intuitive to use maps as functions, but from mathematical point of view (and functional programming is close to maths) function _is a_ map. In general, function is a relation that maps some input set X to some output set Y, no difference whether this relation is analytical (e.g. formula) or elementwise (like key-value map). For example, grayscale image `I` may be considered as a function that maps pair of coordinates `(x, y)` to a pixel value, i.e. `I(x, y) = value`. So it makes sense to make maps implement `IFn` in Clojure. (Keywords implement it just for convenience, though).

Comment: Also worth noting, symbols implement ifn - `('a '{a 0 b 1 c 2})`